# How to get detailed information from an STL file for the manufacturer?

Tags: troubleshooting, stl

I am trying to get a file produced by a manufacturer and they want the detailed dimensions of the model, it is a complex ID card badge holder and I am wondering if there is an easier way to get a dimension sheet. I have used Fusion 360 to get like face and edge measurements but there are a lot and I was seeing if there was a better way to do it?

Comment: Can't you make a technical drawing in Fusion? The design tool is meant to produce drawings for fabrication shops.

Comment: @0scar I did not create the file in Fusion 360 it was just an STL file that I aquired.

Comment: An STL can be transformed into a solid, and from a solid you can make drawings. Can you add an image of the STL, or a reference to the model?